# WPF Issue with TemplateBinding

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008

I am using VS2008.  I have this class

```
[System.Windows.Markup.ContentProperty("Child")]
public class CaptionedBox : Control
{
    static CaptionedBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CaptionedBox), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CaptionedBox)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShadeVisibilityProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ShadeVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(CaptionedBox), new 
         PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden));
}
```

and this code in a ResourceDictionary (in a file called Generic.xaml)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type wft:CaptionedBox}">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Rectangle Fill="#44000000" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShadeVisibility}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

There are no errors, no problems, I use this CaptionedBox all over the place.

I have another XAML page in the same project that references this ResourceDictionary with Source="../Themes/Generic.xaml".  When I open that page, it says "The resource dictionary XAML file has errors and cannot be loaded."  It is referring to the Generic.XAML at that point.  If I double click on the error message, even with Generic.XAML open in VS 2008, I get a different tab for what looks like a different Generic.xaml, except that the contents are identical and if I copy the full path for each of the tabs, I see this:

C:\Source\LyonsForge\root\PumpServicing\branches\PSRT_1_0_2\Code\Bench\Controls\Wizard..\Themes\Generic.xaml
C:\Source\LyonsForge\root\PumpServicing\branches\PSRT_1_0_2\Code\Bench\Controls\Themes\Generic.xaml

which, although a bit awkward, are the same path.

Any clues?

Comment: Other things I have done while researching:  deleted all obj and bin folders, cleaned and rebuilt entire project, searched entire hard-drive for other instances of Generic.Xaml....rebooted :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already make your generic.xaml to be copy local? Also don't forget to set the option on the property of the file: "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always", because the generic.xaml is not meant to be compiled.

Comment: What is the difference between "copy local" and "Copy to output directory"?  This app has been running for two years with copy to output directory = Do Not Copy.  But I tried changing it to Copy Always anyway.  Got the same error.